# Issue while applying where clause for parent table : Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

**Below is the schema for tblagegroup**

```
CREATE TABLE `tblagegroup` (
  `AgeGroupID` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `MinAge` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `MaxAge` int(11) NOT NULL
);
```

**Below is the schema for tblcontentlibrary**

```
CREATE TABLE `tblcontentlibrary` (
  `ContentLibraryID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AgeGroupID` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);
```

AgeGroupID is associated in both tables.

I am trying to get those records from tblcontentlibrary where MinAge >= 2 and MaxAge is <= 4

Below is what i tried.

```
\App\Models\ContentLibraryModel
::with('AgeGroup')
->where('MinAge', '>=', $years)
->where('MaxAge', '<=', $years)
->get();
```

I am getting below error.

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'MinAge' in 'where clause' (SQL:
>   select * from `tblcontentlibrary` where `MinAge` >= 0 and `MaxAge` <=
>   0)

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your relations are correct, [this should work](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads):

```
\App\Models\ContentLibraryModel::with(['AgeGroup' => function ($query) use ($years) {
    $query->where('MinAge', '>=', $years)->where('MaxAge', '<=', $years);
}])->get();
```

Comment: **explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given** I am now getting this error.

Comment: Almost fixed. But it does not now return data from table tblagegroup. I am getting data from onlytblcontentlibrary

Comment: To make it work you should setup proper relationship with proper foreign keys, like here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: It shows correct data when I wrote it like this `\App\Models\ContentLibraryModel::with(['AgeGroup' => function ($query) use ($years) {
                    $query->where('MinAge', '>=', $years)->where('MaxAge', '<=', $years);
                }])->with('AgeGroup')->get();` Do you know why do i need to include `AgeGroup` twice?

Comment: I do not see your real table data, but probably the problem is in `>=` and '<='. I guess it should be '<=' and '>='. But again, I do not see your real data so it may be wrong assumption.

Comment: Well, as I told you, the problem was in `<=` and `>=`. I think you can make it work with Eloquent as you originally wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Use `whereHas` to condition a return based on a relation.

```
\App\Models\ContentLibraryModel::with('AgeGroup')
    ->whereHas('AgeGroup', function ($query) use ($years) {
        $query->where('MinAge', '>=', $years);
        $query->where('MaxAge', '<=', $years);
    })
    ->get();
```

This will only return models whose AgeGroup fits that criteria (`whereHas`), and will also return the AgeGroup relation (`with`).

More info:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

My working query is below.

```
\App\Models\ContentLibraryModel
    ::selectRaw('CL.*, AG.MinAge, AG.MaxAge')
    ->from('tblcontentlibrary as CL')
    ->join('tblagegroup as AG', 'AG.AgeGroupID', '=', 'CL.AgeGroupID')
    ->where('AG.MinAge', '<=', $years)
    ->where('AG.MaxAge', '>=', $years)
    ->get();
```